# nordvpn login problems using raspberry pi from command line

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to use nordvpn from raspberry pi using raspbian.
First of all I used the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update the packages, then I used `sudo apt install nordvpn` to install nord vpn.
After entering the command `sudo nordvpn login` and entering my credentials I always get the message "Whoops! We're having trouble reaching our servers. Please try again later. If the issue persists, please contact our customer support."

how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because reboot step was missed.

1. Reboot using `sudo reboot`
2. Once rebooted - adjust user privilages `su - $USER`
3. Attempt connection `nordvpn connect`

Comment: thanks, after a reboot it works correctly